# Writing Dapper Query for Nested Objects

Tags: orm, dapper

I have a code Structure as below:

```
class Person
{
    Name PersonName;
    int Age;
}

class Name
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Stored Proc which populates the data from Database.

```
Create Procedure SpGetAllPersons
As
Select FirstName, LastName, Age from Persons
```

How do I write Dapper query  which pulls all the Person from Database?

Example:

`List<Person> Persons = DbConn.Query<Person>("SpGetAllPersons", CommandType.StoredProcedure);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the multi mapper if you want to select nested objects.

This should work:

```
List<Person> persons = DbConn.Query<Name,Person,Person>
  ("SpGetAllPersons",
     (name,person) => {person.Name = name; return person;} 
     commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, 
     splitOn: "Age");
```

The multi-mapper can return any type, even just an aggregate type that is not mapped to any db table.

It is important to supply the `splitOn` param if you intend to split on anything that is not called `id` or `Id`.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had to swap the position of Name: `.Query<Person, Name, Person>(..., (person, name) => ... )`.  Also, splitOn: "Age" isn't working for me either - I keep getting this error: "When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id"

Comment: I misunderstood what splitOn was actually doing... that part is working fine... but I still needed to swap `Name`